# EC private key and domain parameters using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve

First of all, sorry for my ignorance, I'm new at cryptography. I'm trying to generate a public key for use with elliptic curves given the private key.

So, at the moment I have:

1. The curve I will be using `y^2 = x^3 - ax + b` (prime256v1)
2. A ***`.pem`*** file with a private key.

The first question is, does the private key have to be random? I mean, can it be whatever I want?

When I use the OpenSSL command:

```
openssl ecparam -in private.pem -name prime256v1 -out public.pem
```

If I do a cat of ***`public.pem`*** I get:

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BggqhkjOPQMBBw==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
```

But there is no public key.

The second question is, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is somewhat off topic here as it is just about command line usage. But it's X-mas. Next time, use superuser please.

Comment: @Maarten - I was ready to cast the close, but I'm going to follow your lead. [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> A .pem file with a private key. I have here the first question. The private key can be random? I mean, can it be whatever I want?

No. The parameter S of the private key can be random, but the ASN.1 -> DER -> PEM *encoded* private key - which includes the parameters - can't.

> `openssl ecparam -in private.pem -name prime256v1 -out public.pem` ... But there is no public key, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

You need to use the `ec` command instead, and use `-pubout`. The `.pem` that you are currently getting simply contains the name of the curve encoded as OID:

```
echo "BggqhkjOPQMBBw==" | openssl base64 -d | openssl asn1parse -inform DER
```

result:

```
0:d=0  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :prime256v1
```